# Como obtener los datos de un documento excel c# asp.net (LIBERERIA OpenXML)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buenas compañeros colegas estoy buscando la forma que con la Libreria OpenXML cargar los datos de un archivo EXCEL, este es el codigo que tengo en el controlador solo que me marca null en la variable row, me podrian ayudar a decirme cual es el error o una alternativa el objetivo anteriormente planteado

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegistrarPorDocumento(string file)
    {
        string file2 = @"D:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Archivo.xlsx";
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/"+file);

        var data = new List<Pesaje>();
        using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {
            var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
            var rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var fields = row.Elements<Cell>().Select(c => c.InnerText).ToArray();
                var record = new Pesaje
                {
                    FechaEntrada = Convert.ToDateTime(fields[1]), 
                    FechaEntrada = Convert.ToDateTime(fields[2]), 
                    Boleto = fields[3],
                };
                data.Add(record);
            }
        }
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías de favor de compartirnos el error que te aparece a ti?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día y saludos.

Para interpretar ese valor use [Open XML SDK 2.0 to get access to excel 2010 worksheet by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813322/open-xml-sdk-2-0-to-get-access-to-excel-2010-worksheet-by-name) (está en inglés):

```
private string GetCellValue(Cell cell, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813322/open-xml-sdk-2-0-to-get-access-to-excel-2010-worksheet-by-name
    if (cell == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var value = cell.CellFormula != null
        ? cell.CellValue.InnerText
        : cell.InnerText.Trim();

    // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
    // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
    // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
    // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
    // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
    // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
    // the words TRUE or FALSE.
    if (cell.DataType == null)
    {
        return value;
    }
    switch (cell.DataType.Value)
    {
        case CellValues.SharedString:

            // For shared strings, look up the value in the
            // shared strings table.
            var stringTable =
                workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            // If the shared string table is missing, something 
            // is wrong. Return the index that is in
            // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
            // the table.
            if (stringTable != null)
            {
                value =
                    stringTable.SharedStringTable
                        .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
            }
            break;

        case CellValues.Boolean:
            switch (value)
            {
                case "0":
                    value = "FALSE";
                    break;
                default:
                    value = "TRUE";
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

La función anterior devuelve un `string`; entonces buscando en la web encontre que el valor allí en el Excel no esta directo; se requiere convertir el valor, para ello hice lo siguiente implememtación haciendo uso de **`DateTime.FromOADate`** que con ello medio el valor correcto (la función en caso de fallo devuelve `null`); para tu caso (al vuelo) puede te sirva de la siguiente forma:

```
private DateTime? CellValueDateTimeNull(Cell cell, WorkbookPart pWorkbookPart)
{
    var fields = row.Elements<Cell>().Select(c => c.InnerText).ToArray();
    string valor = GetCellValue(cell, pWorkbookPart);

    if (valor == null)
        return null;
    else
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(valor));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

} // CellValueDateTimeNull
```

En tu código (en la parte respectiva) sería:

```
var record = new Pesaje
{
   FechaEntrada = CellValueDateTimeNull(fields[1], spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart), 
   FechaEntrada = CellValueDateTimeNull(fields[2], spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart), 
   Boleto = fields[3],
};
```

Espero te sirva u oriente en tu situación. **Importante: Fijate que tienes en la clase dos veces `FechaEntrada`**